# Would it be bad practice to have a sacrificial process for the OoM killer in Kubernetes?

Tags: java, kubernetes

For containers with low memory limits (few hundred of MBs) for applications that allocate sections of their memory in percentage like Java applications (so not easy to just increase limit of a few MB for example), would it be considered a bad practice to include a sacrificial process to enable the application to terminates gracefully instead of being killed in case of the OoM killer being triggered?

Just a simple concept like that:

- Spawn small process locking a defined amount of memory (for example 16 or 32MB) in resident memory (so count as used memory in the cgroups limit)
- Set the `oom_score_adj` of this sacrificial process to `1000` so that its total `oom_score` is always >= 0
- Set the `oom_score_adj` of the application process to `0` so that its total `oom_score` is always <= 0
- Have a background daemon or thread monitoring the sacrificial process, if it gets killed then send `SIGTERM` (or whatever else to notify the app to stop) so it can try to gracefully finish current treatments and stop instead of being immediately killed if the memory freed by the killed sacrificial process enabled the pod to remain behind the memory limit until it completely stopped

One drawback of doing this I see is that it would be dependent of the OoM implementation and is not portable, if it changes or the container is based on Windows instead of Linux for example then it wouldn't work.

Beside this, do you have any idea of why it would be bad practice or idea to handle OoM issues like this?

Comment: How would this help?  If any sacrificial process actually uses physical, non-virtual RAM, it's deliberately wasting scarce resources.  And if it doesn't actually use physical non-virtual RAM, getting killed by [the out-of-fuel killer](https://lwn.net/Articles/104185/) won't change things and the next target will be killed.  If you need reliability, disable memory overcommit, disable the OOM killer, and don't run stupidly-designed applications that blindly assume they can ask for all kinds of memory they never use.

Comment: Yes I know it's basically wasting a bit memory but in this case that's pretty much the idea so it's used a buffer freeing a bit memory when it occurs. I don't expect this to totally protect against the OoM killer, just increase the probability of being able to stop correctly above 0 compared to right now. Let's say I don't have the ability to administrate the cluster itself, not able to choose the language and frameworks of the apps and just deploy pods and their configuration (so for example setting the memory limit) while still trying to not just setting the limit sky high.

Comment: If you have a java process you'd better detect sudden spikes and run memory/commitment profiling, as for OOMs you should first limit the maximum memory of jvm(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c755fFv1Rnk) then enable shutdown on OOM from inside the java -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError and dont forget to enable -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError (and ensure that  heap dump is collected to some shared volume and persisted between containers and removed periodically because only first one wins over the latter ones)

Comment: And to be fair, even if Java is indeed a memory hog, calls to memory allocation always succeed even beyond the limit (so it doesn't help the app) and the memory used can increase inside a pod without allocating memory but by just touching new pages of code and it will then stay here as there's no swap

Comment: You can enable -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch in java for testing. P.S. and don't forget to enable JFR recording and record to the shared or per container folder, JFR is supposed to work in production

Comment: Hmm thanks for the ExitOnOutOfMemoryError I didn't know about it, I'll try if it works but I fear even for the JVM it shouldn't be able to survive long enough after the Linux OoM killer triggers as it sends SIGKILL to processes no? The main issue is the OoM caused by the non-heap memory touched and triggering the OoM killer immediately once the pod uses more memory than the limit (as there's no swap nor any memory overcommit system enabled). Simplest solution by far is of course to just increase the memory limit of the deployment

Comment: You can monitor out of the heap allocations (with XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary), and once again I suggest you to start async profiler after the spikes(i personaly use a bash script than runs in background and starts profiling if sh happens) , so that you would be able to track down the leak if there is one

Comment: Yes I'm already setting heap size, enabling the AlwaysPreTouch option and have JFR recordings. I also set the MALLOC_ARENA_MAX environment variable and have regular calls to System.trim_native_heap diagnostic command to reduce native memory fragmentation but the real issue is trying to cleanly handle random surges of non-heap memory usages from the JVM without requesting too much memory for pods that normally don't need it and on the other end being able to cleanly stop them instead of them being immediately killed

Comment: My current solution is watch for the sudden spikes and quickly run some quick profiling and collecting reports like top, pmap, state of native memory etc.

Comment: I'm already past this and I'm talking about processes not with a leaky straight increasing curve of memory usage, just crashs occurring when the pod is heavily stressed and running very close to the limit so that just few MBs of memory suddenly used by the JVM for whatever it needs at that time is enough to get it killed, mainly just recompiling bytecode... But I'll stop here anyway, I can perfectly understand why anyone would find this situation absurd and not understand the reason outside of context as this is mainly a money-related issue. Thanks for your help and time :)